# __name__ and __qualname__ missing in object

Tags: python

I have a deeply nested object and recently I found out that people are performing `__qualname__` to get the path of nested object but mine seem to be missing this two magic function. I am currently using Python 3.6.

object class

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, dict1):
        self.__dict__.update(dict1)
```

Function to convert dictionary to nested objects:

```
def dict2obj(dict1):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(dict1), object_hook=node)
```

load json to dictionary and convert it:

```
abc = dict2obj(json.load(open("example.json")))
```

The whole thing convert JSON file to nested objects, so I can navigate through the object like `abc.foo.bar` and I would like to perform `abc.foo.bar.__name__` which return `'bar'` and `abc.foo.bar.__qualname__` which return `'abc.foo.bar'` but both of this magic function seems to be missing.

Comment: Please provide *something* that amounts to details and clarity or an [mre] so that we can actually say anything about the situation. Right now all we can tell you is what you already know.

Comment: The `__name__` and `__qualname__` attributes are only available for named functions and classes

Comment: Specifically, it applies only to the class itself, not to instances of the class

Comment: I just edited the post, do you guys know anything similar to my usecase? especially for the __qualname__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can never be such a function in python. When you define a class or function, `__name__` is set to the name of the function:

```py
class A:
    pass

A.__name__
# prints "A"
```

The `class` keyword sets this variable, it is *not* a function and won't be set later if you assign A to another variable:

```
class A:
    pass
B = A
B.__name__
# Still prints "A", since only the class keyword sets name, not reassignment
```

## Qualname

A module object also has a `__name__` set by import, that is why you see `if __name__ == "__main__"` for executable python scripts to make sure they are not executed if imported.

If you have a file like this:

a.py

```
print __name__
```

b.py

```
import a
```

This will print `a`.

If you define a class in `a.py`, the `__qualname__` will be the global module level variable `__name__` concatenated with the classes own `__name__`

a.py

```
class A:
    pass
print(A.__qualname__)
```

b.py

```
import a
```

This will print `a.A`

## Why it is impossible for such a variable to exist

Any object can have multiple references. Which name to use? Assume a function `get_full_path` existed that could do what you wanted.

```
def k(m):
    print(get_full_path(m.four[2])) # no such function exists
a = db.users["bob"].name_field
b.all_names = a.names
k(b.all_names[5])
```

What should this print? `m.four[2]` or `db.users["bob"].name_field.names.four[2]` or `b.all_names.four[2]`? They are all equally valid and there is no difference between them.